# Simple time function to calculate waiting time

Tags: php, datetime, timestamp

I am trying to get a simple time function to work using PHP to calculate the waiting time of a patient. The Arrival time inputs into the patient table as a TIMESTAMP successfully; here is the piece of code for this;

```
// validate arrival time 

$date_time=date('Y-m-d H:i:sa');

clock time
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
$the_time1 = date('G:ia');
```

waiting time would be (the clock time - the arrival time)

However, this isn't working in my piece of code!

```
<?php

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","") or die ("No connection");
mysqli_select_db($conn, "a&e") or die('Could not select database.');

$query = "SELECT PatientID, Forename, Surname, Gender, Illness, Priority, Arrival_Time FROM Patient";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die("Invalid query");

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
$the_time1 = date('G:ia');
$date_time=date('Y-m-d H:i:sa');

echo Waiting_time($the_time1, $date_time); 

function waiting_time ( $the_time1, $date_time) {

$time_diff =  ( $the_time1, $date_time); {
$days      = floor( $time_diff / 86400 ); // 60 * 60 * 24 = number of seconds in a day
$time_diff -= $days * 86400;
$hours      = floor( $time_diff / 3600 ); // 60 * 60 = number of seconds in a hour
$time_diff -= $hours * 3600;
$mins       = floor( $time_diff / 60 ); // 60 = number of seconds in a minute

return( $days . ' days, ' . $hours . ' hours, ' . $mins . ' minutes' );

}


echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>PatientID</th>
<th>Forename</th>
<th>Surname</th>
<th>Gender</th>
<th>Illness</th>
<th>Priority</th>
<th>Waiting Time</th>
</tr>";

}
  echo "<tr>
  <td>" . $row[0] . "</td>
  <td>" . $row[1] . "</td>
  <td>" . $row[2] . "</td>
  <td>" . $row[3] . "</td>
  <td>" . $row[4] . "</td>
  <td>" . $row[5] . "</td>
  <td>" . $waitTime . "</td>
  </tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

EDIT;

I have now changed the code to this;

```
<?php

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","") or die ("No connection");
mysqli_select_db($conn, "a&e") or die('Could not select database.');

$query = "SELECT PatientID, Forename, Surname, Gender, Illness, Priority, Arrival_Time as Waiting_Time FROM Patient";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die("Invalid query");

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>PatientID</th>
<th>Forename</th>
<th>Surname</th>
<th>Gender</th>
<th>Illness</th>
<th>Priority</th>
<th>Waiting_Time</th>
</tr>";

 while ($row = $result->fetch_object()){


  echo "<tr>
  <td>" . $row->PatientID . "</td>
  <td>" . $row->Forename . "</td>
  <td>" . $row->Surname . "</td>
  <td>" . $row->Gender . "</td>
  <td>" . $row->Illness . "</td>
  <td>" . $row->Priority . "</td>
  <td>" . $row->Waiting_Time . "</td>
  </tr>";

}

echo "</table>";
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

This is now displaying the data as the following;

```
PatientID Forename Surname Gender Illness     Priority Waiting_Time 
249       Sara     Kearns  F      Immediate   high     2013-03-20 22:18:01
```

I need the waiting time to display in hours e.g. 1:15:23

Comment: there's an extra { inside the function

Comment: yeah, i am getting this error "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',' on line 17"

Comment: There's also 2 extra } in there too :)

Comment: ok You've got your SQL statement wrong.  Compare what you have vs what I have in my code below.

Comment: I used your SQL statement but it throws up a invalid query error; the SQL statement used above is the only one I've found works.

Comment: well the one above is simply converting your Arrival_Time column to a column to be called Waiting_Time.  So its clearly NOT working.  You have to DATEDIFF() inside the sql query and cast it out as a virtual colum (thats teh as Waiting_Time bit!) so you can get the difference between the 2 time stamps.
As mentioned before help yourself I'm not going to hand it to you on a plate. If its saying there's a sql query error then I've put you on the right tracks I suggest you hit the mysql docs for further help. perhaps here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: I've updated the sql query to use TIMEDIFF() actually may be better for you than DATEDIFF() so check the syntax of that and implement accordingly

Comment: Yeah, it's not working. Not sure how to get it working...but thanks for your help, much appreciated.

Comment: Okay, that displaying data as -110:21:47

Comment: swap now and date input string around to give you a positive time. thats 110 hours, 21 minutes, 47 seconds waiting.

Comment: A patient can't be waiting 110 hours to be seen...

Comment: In your case it can your arrival time is 2013-03-20 22:18:01 and its now the 25th. So for your example posted above it is 110 hours waiting.  Of course we're comparing against NOW() which is the time at the query run.  If you store a Leave_Time column (which you don't mention anywhere) then you'd time stamp against that instead of NOW()

Comment: Ahh I see, so if I add a new patient it should be lower. Is there a function to display data in real-time (continuously update). And thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Yes if you use a more recent date it'll show a more accurate time its just in your case your using old data. There's no way to do it in real time. You'd have to create a script that self refreshed every say 10 seconds.  Which if you use the page I've posted before is a simple question of adding a javascript setTimeout function to the bottom of the page and have it auto redirect to itsself. One line of code and it'll do exactly what you want.

Comment: awesome, many thanks for your help! What do I do to correct the minus data?

Comment: In the sql statement just swap the Arrival_Time,NOW() to be NOW(),Arrival_Time

Comment: I updated the records in the database, waiting_time isnt working now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do it in the sql query since you already have the arrival time in the DB

```
$query = "SELECT PatientID, Forename, Surname, Gender, Illness, Priority, Arrival_Time, TIMEDIFF(Arrival_time,NOW()) as Waiting_Time FROM Patient";
```

Also in your example above your only ever comparing now time to now time never actually comparing against Arrival_Time from your DB

**Example modified version of your code**

```
<?php

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","") or die ("No connection");
mysqli_select_db($conn, "a&e") or die('Could not select database.');

$query = "SELECT PatientID, Forename, Surname, Gender, Illness, Priority, Arrival_Time , TIMEDIFF(Arrival_time,NOW()) as Waiting_Time FROM Patient";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die("Invalid query");

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>PatientID</th>
<th>Forename</th>
<th>Surname</th>
<th>Gender</th>
<th>Illness</th>
<th>Priority</th>
<th>Waiting Time</th>
</tr>";

 while ($row = $result->fetch_object()){


  echo "<tr>
  <td>" . $row[0] . "</td>
  <td>" . $row[1] . "</td>
  <td>" . $row[2] . "</td>
  <td>" . $row[3] . "</td>
  <td>" . $row[4] . "</td>
  <td>" . $row[5] . "</td>
  <td>" . $row[7] . "</td>
  </tr>";

}

echo "</table>";
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',' on line 17; which is this line; 
$time_diff =  ( $the_time1, $date_time);

Comment: you don't need that any more remove it all

Comment: If I delete it, it displays as invalid query. What exactly should i delete?

Comment: Invalid query has nothing to do with your $time_diff line etc your current time diff code etc at current has absolubtly nothing to do with the query at all.  If its throwing a query error then there's a query in your sql (which I didn't check I just added the date diff stuff) you can look up the exact syntax of date_diff() on the mysql website.

Comment: I have used your code and following error occurs; Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array on line 25

Comment: Yeah I messed up a little instead of $row[0] it whould be `$row->PatientID` etc something you could probably have worked out yourself by reading the mysqli docs.  We're here to help not do all your work for you.  A little bit of common sense is required.

Comment: Okay, I will try to correct it. In the code you have provided, you haven't added the calculation (clock time - arrival time) to get the waiting time. Why is this

Comment: Its in the sql statement as date_diff() as stated both in my answer and in a comment. Your php based calculations are no longer needed as its all done in DB.

Comment: Okay i have it displaying all the data apart from waiting time; ERROR Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$Waiting_Time on line 32.

Comment: its not `$Waiting_Time` its `$row->Waiting_Time`

Comment: Also check you've updated your SQL query to match mine above.

Comment: I am going to edit my question to illustrate what is displaying;

Comment: OK I'll look once you've posted up what code you're using now.

Comment: I have posted an edit to the question