# display waiting time using PHP

Tags: php, datetime, time

I want to display the waiting time for a patient using this simple calculation;

```
waiting time (the clock time - the arrival time)
```

In the insert form; I have used the following code to insert the current_time (arrival_time) into the PATIENT table which has been successful.

```
// validate arrival time 
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
$time = time();

$sql="INSERT INTO Patient(Forename, Surname, Gender, Date_Of_Birth, Address, Patient_History, Illness, Priority, Arrival_Time)
VALUES('$patient_name', '$patient_lastname', '$gender', '$date', '$address', '$history', '$illness', '$priority', '$time')";
```

Here is the output code;

```
<?php

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","") or die ("No connection");
mysqli_select_db($conn, "a&e") or die('Could not select database.');

$query = "SELECT PatientID, Forename, Surname, Gender, Illness, Priority, Arrival_Time, TIMEDIFF(Arrival_time,NOW()) as Waiting_Time FROM Patient";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die("Invalid query");

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>PatientID</th>
<th>Forename</th>
<th>Surname</th>
<th>Gender</th>
<th>Illness</th>
<th>Priority</th>
<th>Waiting_Time</th>
</tr>";

 while ($row = $result->fetch_object()){


  echo "<tr>
  <td>" . $row->PatientID . "</td>
  <td>" . $row->Forename . "</td>
  <td>" . $row->Surname . "</td>
  <td>" . $row->Gender . "</td>
  <td>" . $row->Illness . "</td>
  <td>" . $row->Priority . "</td>
  <td>" . $row->Waiting_Time . "</td>
  </tr>";

}

echo "</table>";
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

How would I calculate the waiting time using the following calculation; 
(the clock time - the arrival time)

**Please note: Arrival_Time type is TIME.

Comment: Doesn't `TIMEDIFF(Arrival_time,NOW()) as Waiting_Time` in your query does the same?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply subtract the time in the database from the current time and then format it using [date](http://www.php.net/date)

```
$waiting_time = date("H:i:s", time() - $arrival_time);
```

Answer (score 0):

We've been through this already  today.

[Simple time function to calculate waiting time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15613783/simple-time-function-to-calculate-waiting-time/15613848#15613848)

You don't need to do it in PHP as its done already in your query $row->Waiting_Time is the clock time vs arrival time already.

If you're now looking for a PHP based solution instead of the correct solution then you're clearly attempting to do some homework and I should never have helped you in the first place (more fool me) not only that but you can go tell your lecturer/teacher they're an idiot for forcing you to use a PHP solution that is far better handled by the built in MySQL functions.

Comment: i know i had it working but when i updated the database, the arrival time function wouldnt work!

Comment: thats not a code issue  that a you issue either input date wrong or invalid date format in column.

Comment: the arrival_time in the database is now stored as TIME instead of TIMESTAMP

Comment: same thing. Though why you'd use anything but DATETIME format and use CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as the column defafult is beyond me.  Your db structure is wrong, your implementing bad practice.

Comment: What could i do to correct this?